# How do I query in Azure DevOps to check number of times a bug is failed or reopened

Tags: azure-devops

How do I query in Azure Devops to check number of times a bug is failed or reopened

Answer (score 1):

In case someone looks to display bugs, which were reopened at least once.

- Field: State
- Operator: Was Ever
- Value: Reopen

Answer (score 0):

I would try following this approach:

- get [work item revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)
- iterate over the resulting [list of `WorkItemUpdate` objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#workitemupdate)
- filter it by the `State` field and select those where the `State` field changes from/to `Failed` or from/to `Reopened`

The length of the resulting list is, most likely, the number you need.

NOTE: I may not be 100% accurate in the names of the field or states, but I'm sure you get the idea.